# How to move menu only in jfeinstein10's SlidingMenu, fix main layout

Tags: android, slidingmenu

Is it possible toggle SlidingMenu, without changing main layouts position in jfeinstein's SlidingMenu library?

Comment: why downvote? without giving a reason, not everyone is genius!

Comment: i have used this library and i didn't find any way to achieve this..it's not supported in this lib. Only option available is whether to move actionbar along with sliding menu or not using( setSlidingActionBarEnabled(false))

Comment: Thanks @Akhil, Could you find any other way to achieve it?

Comment: you can use [native navigation drawer](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html)...

Comment: Thanks @Akhil, here is link what I wanted to implement http://www.coderzheaven.com/2013/06/28/navigation-drawer-android, I will accept Marcin Orlowski's answer, since he also gave me some idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not recall any parameter to set the bahavior that way. But you can always use SlidingPaneLayout from support lib: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SlidingPaneLayout.html

Comment: Thanks @MarcinOrlowski I need similar behaivior when it comes to pane, pane which is behind should be static, but if I use it in tablet, both pane's are visible, by requirement it should be sliding type of pane. (very similar to sliding menu, but background pane should be static, not moveable)

Comment: You still can have separate "host" for phone and tablet and since I assume your layout components are based on fragments, it should not make any difference if one host is using slidingpane while other jfeinsten slide menu